# Zurb foundation last column overflows onto next line

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I've got a simple column layout using Zurb Foundation 5:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="small-1 columns">1</div>
        <div class="small-10 columns">10</div>
        <div class="small-1 columns">1</div>
</div>
```

But below a certain width the last column breaks out onto the next line, even though there is plenty of room for all the content.

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/kqscrxpq/

Edit: I'd like to understand why it's doing this, particularly in light of the apparent free space still available, and then hopefully find an appropriate fix.

Comment: Is there a question? It's doing that because of padding. Remove the padding from the `.small-1` and you're set.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean *"because of padding"*. The padding is obviously an intrinsic part of the framework's layout, acting as guttering, so it seems odd I should have to mess about with it in this simple scenario. Nevertheless I did try your suggestion but removing all padding from the final column didn't appear to help.

Comment: I removed padding in your example and it worked fine for me. Keep in mind, Foundation isn't meant to go so tiny that no small device exists at that ratio. You *can* create a `xsmall` breakpoint if you wish, however. This would take the smaller padding into consideration and allow for such a small viewport.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the padding of `small-1` column is fixed 30px in total and when width of `small-1` column gets less than the padding, the column breaks to next line.

e.g if window size is 359px the size of column will be `8.333333 % of 359px = 29.91px` which is less than the padding so the width of column will not be less 30px. The remaining space is 29.91px and 30px column will break to next line.